# Compilation Error while executing maven project through Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to execute maven project through jenkins but getting this error. I have not changed the default permission settings::

```
Started by user kashmir
Building in workspace C:\Users\kashmir\.jenkins\workspace\Test.SampleItem
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 52587
[Test.Sample] $ /bin/java -cp C:\Users\kashmir\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar;C:\Users\kashmir\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\TestMaven\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Users\kashmir\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\TestMaven/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main C:\Users\kashmir\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\TestMaven C:\Users\kashmir\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.17.jar C:\Users\kashmir\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar C:\Users\kashmir\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12-alpha-1.jar 52587
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/java" (in directory "C:\Users\kashmir\Documents\SELENIUM_PROJECT\Test.Sample"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:929)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:278)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:236)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:804)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1727)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
Did not find any matching files.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Your Java binary cannot be found. Try and log on to the machine where your tests are running and see if the environmental variable JAVA_HOME is set and the folder with the java executable in is in your path.

Comment: @Homewrecker, environment variable is set and folder path is added in PATH variable.

Comment: `Cannot run program "/bin/java"` and `The system cannot find the file specified`. `/bin/java` looks weird for what looks like a Windows machine (`C:\Users\kashmir...`)